# How do you automatically call a python script to run a job on an already open and created abaqus model?

Tags: python, fortran, abaqus

I am doing a multiscale analysis on abaqus using UMAT, UEL and python script. I would like to be able to call in my UMAT a python script that automatically creates and runs a job for my already created macro model.

I have tried to call it using cmd with the following commends

```
CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE('abaqus cae script=jobsub.py') 
CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE('abaqus viewer script=jobsub.py')
CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE('abaqus cae noGUI=jobsub.py')
CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE('abaqsub.cae script=jobsub.py')
CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE('abaqsub.cae viewer script=jobsub.py')
```

I expect it to be able to run automatically the python script to create a job and run it for an existing model abaqsub.cae.
However, in all cases it either creates a new abaqus viewerport and tries to run the job (which doesn't work because the script is only made to run a job not to create a model) or it runs the model that I already have and doesn't create the job.

Comment: if you show as the contents of jobsub.py maybe we can help

Comment: I don't think there's a way to control an opened session from outside of Abaqus. The only alternative I see is doing something as constantly tailing a text file with those commands and running them from that opened Abaqus CAE session.